# jQuery Click Event Code Repeats Infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hVLsk/2/

Relevant code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
           var element = $('#image');
           var mouseX = e.pageX - element.offset().left;
           var mouseY = e.pageY - element.offset().top;
           if(mouseX >= 0 && mouseY >= 0) {
               $('#coords').html(mouseX + ', ' + mouseY);
           }
           element.click(function() {
             //  if(mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 150 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
                   $('#div1').fadeToggle();
               // }
           });
       });
    });
```

More of a server side programmer myself so my JavaScript and jQuery isn't the best but I can normally do simple hover and click events fine, this has just stumped me.

What I want to do by the end is have different boxes fade in when you click a certain area of the image, that part is all fine (I have commented it out), but the problem is that whatever I put inside that click event repeats with no stopping.

I have tried unbinding the click event (though I'm not sure that's even relevant to the situation), and using simple alerts instead of the fading to no avail.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You are binding the onclick event of the element every time the mouse moves. It maybe does not come from here, but when you have such a misconception in your code, you should first fix it before looking for the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are registering infinite number of `click` events to the `image` element as the mouse is moved across the page.

The solution is to register a single `click` event handler and use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to track the mouse as given below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var mouseX, mouseY, element = $('#image');
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
                mouseX = e.pageX - element.offset().left;
                mouseY = e.pageY - element.offset().top;
                if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseY >= 0) {
                    $('#coords').html(mouseX + ', ' + mouseY);
                }
            });
    element.click(function() {
        // if(mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 150 && mouseY >=
        // 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
        $('#div1').fadeToggle();
            // }
        });
});
```

Comment: Hah, knew it was to do with scope and having it inside the function, should've tried that, thanks very much! Will mark as answer.

Comment: I know I should probably ask a new question but it's only small, how would I define mouseX and mouseY as global in this instance?  When I do it outside the function 'e' is undefined, I'm not really sure what the 'e' even means, I know it's passed as a parameter...

Comment: do you want to use `mouseX` outside current scope?

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var element = $('#image');
var mouseX
var mouseY
   $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
       mouseX = e.pageX - element.offset().left;
       mouseY = e.pageY - element.offset().top;
       if(mouseX >= 0 && mouseY >= 0) {
           $('#coords').html(mouseX + ', ' + mouseY);
       }
   });
    element.click(function() {
         //  if(mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 150 && mouseY >= 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
               $('#div1').fadeToggle();
           // }
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var element = $('#image');
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {  
                var mouseX = e.pageX - element.offset().left;
                var mouseY = e.pageY - element.offset().top;
                if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseY >= 0) {
                    $('#coords').html(mouseX + ', ' + mouseY);
                }
            });
           element.click(function() {
        // if(mouseX >= 100 && mouseX <= 150 && mouseY >=
        // 100 && mouseY <= 150) {
        $('#div1').fadeToggle();
            // }
        });
});
```